# Fortran program segfaults when compiled with armflang at -Ofast level

Tags: armflang

I have a Fortran program, which works with `armflang` at `-O3` level but segfaults at `-Ofast` optimization level. What could be going wrong?

Update: The problem is not specific to a workload. This happens for certain NCAR workloads and WRF 3.9.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because of the `-fstack-arrays` option which is enabled by default at `-Ofast` level. As per Arm Fortran Compiler [armflang documentation](https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/hpc/arm-fortran-compiler/compiler-options), `-fstack-arrays` is not enabled at `-O3` level.

The `-fstack-arrays` option places automatic arrays of all sizes on the local stack. This usually leads to better performance as it avoids indirect calls to `malloc()` and `free()` for local and for temporary arrays. On typical Linux systems, stack-size per process is 8192 kB by default (which usually can be increased because the hard limit is "unlimited"). This creates a problem for programs with huge arrays, leading to non-obvious segfaults.

There are two ways to work around this problem

1. Use `-Ofast -fno-stack-arrays` instead, which will disable placing automatic arrays on local stack, but keeps all other `-Ofast` optimizations.
2. Call `ulimit -s unlimited` before running the program if the system permits. This sets the stack to a bigger size than default.

Answer (score 0):

There is no MWE and you have the answer before asking the question !

I am surprised by your choice of -fstack-arrays with -Ofast. I have been reviewing the stack vs heap performance of local and automatic arrays, for both single thread and multi-thread

My experience is that for the situation of stack overflow, ie for larger arrays, there is no significant advantage putting large arrays on the stack. Small arrays do show some performance benefit, especially if they can reside in the cache.
There needs to be a recognition of the array sizes being located in the stack, as a more robust solution is for larger arrays on the heap.

For multi-threading, where each thread has it's own stack, I am showing some benefit of increasing the thread stack size and placing all arrays on the separate stack. In my testing, this appears to reduce the memory coherence problems, although a conclusive proof can be elusive.

I would be interested in your reasoning for your choice of -Ofast and -fstack-arrays. Have you tested a size limit for local and automatic arrays being placed on the stack ?

Comment: The program in question is WRF 3.9.1, so not really possible to provide an MWE.  I debugged issue the hard way and realized that armflang like gfortran includes -fstack-arrays by default, which is not safe and can lead to seg faults. This is nothing unique to armflang or gfortran. This behavior is true even for PGI or other compilers.  This Question and my Answer is to help others in case they are facing a similar issue with armflang. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I am interested in the combining of -Ofast and -fstack-arrays. My expectation is that it is only useful for small arrays. Have you used -fmax-stack-var-size=n as an alternative, although it's application may be limited to local arrays and not automatic arrays ?

Comment: armflang does not support -fmax-stack-var-size=n as of 18.4 release. I agree that if it did, that would be a better option to use.